# How to input a 3d model into ML algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, data, 3d-reconstruction

I have a machine learning model that uses csv with measured data about buildings: width, length, height etc. I use it to predict some features and it works properly.

I would like to drop csv with length, height and width, and I would like to use some kind of algorithm to parse 3d model into the ML algorithm.

The second reason is to try this approach with nonrectangular buildings, which are hard to describe in simple csv generated by humans.

I do not necessarily need the algorithm to read the width, length etc. but to be able to predict some values based on training set of 3d models acompanied by csv with results.

What should I look into? Where can I find information about this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Convolutional Neural Networks can work with 3 dimensional data, and they don't require much feature engineering. Provided you have enough training data, that seems like a way to go. As long as your data is in the form of a grid it is actually easy-peasy. Just imagine an image-like pipeline, but of the form [x,y,z,n]. Where n is the number of examples. *As opposed to [x,y,n] (black and white) or [x,y,c,n] (color-channels).*

It might be the case however that your data is in a vector format (as tends to happen with building models). I do believe there are experiments with straight up graphs and deep learning, but my feeling is that you might be better rasterising your model in that case.

You will probably need to add some layers to compress the data concepts (conv and pools etc) and end with a fully connected layer of 1 node (since you are looking for a scalar).

Comment: Thank you again for answering! My data would probably be 3d solid models (boundary representation) -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_representation
So I suppose this is vector format. 
My target is to predict Energy use based on training set of simulations with 3d model and Energy use results

Comment: Judging form your link a boundary representation is a concept. What is the file format that encodes it , a AutoCAD-file?

Comment: this is up to decision and I could pick the one that is easiest for start, but I would like to get it from a file that is typically used by architects, could be AutoCad, could be Sketchup, could be Rhino 3dm (Preferably), or for example ifc from Revit/Archicad